# Evaluate $\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5+i\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}-i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Evaluate
>   $$\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5+i\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}-i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5$$

I did this by $$\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5=\left(1+\cos\frac{3\pi}{10}+i\sin\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)^5$$ and  get $0$

Does anyone have another idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use the complex e-power?

Comment: "_Does anyone have another idea?_" Could you show us your method?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936196/proving-left-frac1-sin-xi-cos-x1-sin-x-i-cos-x-rightn-cos-n-left-f?rq=1   this post maybe help you!

Comment: @The Jade Reaper, I did this by $\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5=\left(1+\cos\frac{3\pi}{10}+i\sin\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)^5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $z = \sin\frac{\pi}{5}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}$.

$\big($We have $-iz = \cos\frac{\pi}{5}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{5} = \cos\frac{-\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{-\pi}{5}$, so  $\boxed{z^5 = -i}$ by De'Moivre formula.$\big) $

Notice that $\bar{z}={1\over z}$.

Then your expression is \begin{eqnarray}w &=& (1+z)^5+i(1+\bar{z})^5\\
 &=& (1+z)^5+i(1+{1\over z})^5\\
 &=& (1+z)^5+i{(z+1)^5\over z^5}\\
 &=& (1+z)^5+i{(z+1)^5\over -i}\\
 &=& 0\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Aqua,I know this way but I don't  use  binomial theorem

Comment: @ Aqua, this is great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1+\sin x+i\cos x}{1+\sin x-i\cos x}=\frac{(1+\sin x+i\cos x)^2}{(1+\sin x)^2+\cos^2 x}$$

$$=\frac{2(1+\sin x)(\sin x+i\cos x)}{2(1+\sin x)}=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right).$$
Apply de Movire's Theorem, you can get
$$\left(\frac{1+\sin x+i\cos x}{1+\sin x-i\cos x}\right)^n=\cos n\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right)+i\sin n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right).$$
In youe situation, take $x=\pi/5$.
$$\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5+i\left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}-i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^5$$
$$=\left(\frac{1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}}{1+\sin\frac{\pi}{5}-i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}}\right)^5+i=(-i)^5+i=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the facts that $(e^{\pi i/5})^5=e^{\pi i}=-1$ and $i^5=i$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(1+\sin\pi/5+i\cos\pi/5)^5+i(1+\sin\pi/5-i\cos\pi/5)
&=(1+ie^{-\pi i/5})^5+i(1-ie^{\pi i/5})^5\\
&=-(e^{\pi i/5})^5(1+ie^{-\pi i/5})^5+i^5(1-ie^{\pi i/5})^5\\
&=-(e^{\pi i/5}+i)^5+(i+e^{\pi i/5})^5\\
&=0
\end{align}$$